# Java.net.ConnectionException when using Selenium Server

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm seeing java.net Exception errors when running selenium tests.

> Failed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

and

> Failed: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:28686

Current setup

- protractor: 5.4.3
- node: 12.14.0
- Chrome: 80.0.3987.87
- ChromeDriver: 80.0.3987.16
- Webdriver-manager: 12.1.7
- Selenium-server-standalone: 3.141.59

> Config = {
>           seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
>           SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
>           capabilities: {
>             browserName: 'chrome',
>             chromeOptions: {
>               args: [ "--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--apps-keep-chrome-alive-in-tests", "--keep-alive-for-test",
>   "--start-maximized", "--log-level=3", "--headless" , "--disable-gpu",
>   "--window-size=1920,1080"],
>             } 
>           }

If I use directConnect instead of the selenium server, I'm no longer seeing these errors but i can't run the test in parallel while using directConnect.

I've looked up this issue and it seems to be due to Chrome switched over to W3C support. I tried setting w3c to false in the config file as well by using `'w3c': false` in the chromeOptions property but this has no affect.

I've also tried using combinations of older chrome driver/chrome versions, still seeing the errors.

Comment: have you tried removing the `selenuimAddress` altogether ?

Comment: @JoaquinCasco I didn't try that but It looks like the issue is due to the default max instances that it allows. Setting sharedTestFiles: true in the config file seems to have done the trick. Even though in the source it appears to be spelled "shardTestFiles", this value doesn't work when I spell it this way. By default this is set to false which seems to prevent parallel tests.